# Symfony 3 group sequence doesn't work

Tags: symfony

```
ForumBundle\Entity\User:
group_sequence: [User, Admin]
properties:
    login:
        - NotIdenticalTo:
            value: ROOT
            message: 'Login must be different from ROOT!'
    phone:
        - NotBlank:
            message: 'Phone must be present!'
            groups: [Admin]
    granted_by:
        - NotBlank:
            message: 'Your promotor must be present!'
            groups: [Admin]
```

and

```
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setLogin('ROOT');

    $errors = $this
        ->get('validator')
        ->validate(
            $user,
            null,
            array('Admin', 'User')
        );

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        return new Response(
            (string) $errors
        );
    }
    return new Response('ok!');
}
```

Why I have 3 errors on the screen? In my mind firstly the User group should be validated and it should give an error so I shouldn't see any errors more.

Comment: I believe, in your validate method you only should specify the User group, not the Admin group, but I am not certain.

Comment: IIRC you have to omit the groups when calling the `validate()` method when dealing with group sequences.